# I created my own data frame, how can I create a legend in the ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have created my own data.frame and trying to plot it.
However, I just cant get my legend to pop up.

I think something is wrong on the case of the data.frame part.. but not clear

Could anyone please help me?

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                y1=c(1, 3, 5, 6, 3),
                y2=c(2, 4, 1, 3, 4))
data

data_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x), col=group) + geom_smooth(aes(y=y1), color='black') + geom_smooth(aes(y=y2), color='blue') + labs(x="xxx", y="yyy", title="I need help")

data_plot
```

[click to check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8L3k.png)

Comment: You must specify colors inside `aes(...)` otherwise they would not pop up in the automatically generated legend

Answer (score 1):

You must specify colors inside `aes(...)`, otherwise they would not pop up in the automatically generated legend:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame(
  x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
  y1 = c(1, 3, 5, 6, 3),
  y2 = c(2, 4, 1, 3, 4)
)
data
#>   x y1 y2
#> 1 1  1  2
#> 2 2  3  4
#> 3 3  5  1
#> 4 4  6  3
#> 5 5  3  4

data_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x), col = group) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = y1, color = "group 1")) +
  geom_smooth(aes(y = y2, color = "group2")) +
  labs(x = "xxx", y = "yyy", title = "I need help")

data_plot
```

[image]

```r
# long format data frames are better to map group column to color
data %>%
  pivot_longer(matches("y"), values_to = "y") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, color = name)) +
    geom_smooth()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! But then, how do i change the color of the lines?

Comment: @Noobnoob it's ok being a newbie please do some research before asking - the function family you are looking for is `scale_colour_`. [This tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-change-colors-in-ggplot2-line-plot-in-r/) came up in my first result page

Comment: @AndreaM sorry Andrea. I've been actually trying everything for few hours through research, but could not come up with the answer so was asking here. I'll try to be better in the future. thanks

Comment: @Rfanatic I'm not the OP

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `color` in `aes()`, such as `geom_smooth(aes(y=y1, color='black'))` and use `scale_color_identity ()` to assign colours. The default is `guide = "none"` for identity scales.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

    ggplot(data, aes(x), col=group) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=y1, color='black')) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(y=y2, color='blue')) + 
  scale_color_identity(guide = "legend")+
  labs(x="X-axis", y="Y-axis", title="How to make my legend visible", color="Legend")+
  theme_base()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1, face="bold", size=12, color="black"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12, color="black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        legend.text = element_text(color = "black", size = 16,face="bold"),
        legend.title = element_text(face="bold", size=16, color="black"),
        legend.position="top",
        legend.box = "horizontal",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=20, face="bold"))
```

Plot:

[image]

Sample data:

```
data <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
                   y1=c(1, 3, 5, 6, 3),
                   y2=c(2, 4, 1, 3, 4))
data
```